# WordPress display linked tags and max 4

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display tags in my theme, it should be linked to corespondent tag and max tags 4.

I create below code but not sure if has a proper escaping in that code.

```
<p class="the-tags">
    <?php
       $posttags = get_the_tags();
   $count=0;
   if ($posttags) {
       foreach($posttags as $tag) {
          $count++;
          echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a> ';
          if( $count >4 ) break;
       }
   }
       ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Seems to me that it works but... why not trying the code and see by yourself if it behaves as expected?

Comment: Just trying to verify the code, by the way it's placed working and working fine.